# Error: unexpected symbol using the function drop_na

Tags: r, tidyverse

I know drop_na is a tidyverse function, so I installed the packages and everything then ran the code but the function won't work

I am assuming the problem has to do with the name in the parenthesis but I am not entirely sure what the correct label should be for the function to run

```
library(dplyr)
DesignInfo <- read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Documents\\Assignment 3\\design_info.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
InspectionInfo <- read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Documents\\Assignment 3\\inspection_info.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
left_join(DesignInfo, InspectionInfo, by = "weld_id")
library(tidyverse)
drop_na(DesignInfo and InspectionInfo)
```

With this code, the result should be a combine table of DesignInfo and InspectionInfo with no NA values but I end up with the following error message:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "drop_na(DesignInfo and"
```

Comment: `and` isn't a keyword in R. What are you trying to do with that line? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code right, what you really want is this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

DesignInfo <- read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Documents\\Assignment 3\\design_info.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
InspectionInfo <- read.csv(file="C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Documents\\Assignment 3\\inspection_info.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

newData <- DesignInfo %>%
  left_join(InspectionInfo, by = "weld_id") %>%
  drop_na()
```

The pipeline at the end creates a new data set called `newData` using `DesignInfo` as the base. From there, it joins `InspectionInfo` using `weld_id` as the key and then drops all rows that have missing data in any column.

Comment: Yup that's exactly what I wanted as an outcome. I just couldn't figure out how to label my new combined dataset and drop the NAs. Thank you!